# The name IEnumerator does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

This is the most annoying error I've had in a while.
I want to make a simple loop to move my camera to another point in Unity, using C#.

I'm "using System.Collections.Generic", and IEnumerator even shows up in the suggestions when I start typing it, but as soon as I'm done, it goes red and has an error that reads "Assets/Scripts/NerworkManager.cs(190,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IEnumerator' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" in the console, and "error CS0103: The name IEnumerator does not exist in the current context" in the editor.

Here's my code:

```
IEnumerator LerpCam(Camera c, Vector3 target, float length){
        float startTime = Time.time;
        while (Time.time < startTime + length) {
            c.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (c.transform.position, target, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    yield return null;
}
```

I have no idea what the problem is, and am able to use other things from the Generic collection without problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `IEnumerator` is the non-generic interface and resides in `System.Collections`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`IEnumerator` is in `System.Collections` and `IEnumerator<T>` is in `System.Collections.Generic`. So make sure you have the correct matching pair.

Comment: Thanks for that, can't believe I messed up something so simple, every other place was telling me I needed System.Collections.Generic... go figure.

Answer (score 7):

The name 'Enumerable' does not exist because It requires Linq which is available at **Framework 4.0**

And don't forget to use the libraries:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: The using System.Linq worked for me, but the accepted answer didn't for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put

```
using System.Collections;
```

at the top of your file.

Answer (score 2):

I added using System.Collections and I was still getting error "The name 'Enumerable' does not exist in the current context". I added using System.Linq and the error disappeared.

Comment: Note that Enumerator = `System.Linq.Enumerator` and IEnumerator = `System.Collections.IEnumerator`/IEnumerator<T> = `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>`. `Enumerator` and `IEnumerator` are not the same thing. One is the interface and the other is the implementation.