# error cs0103 The Name 'IEnumerator' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I have problem in C# development in **monodevelop** tool for unity.
In that many methods and Interfaces not found like `IEnumerator` and `Array.Length`.

I found  [Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416514/the-name-ienumerator-does-not-exist-in-current-context)  but it's not work for me.
because solution of that question is import System.Collections namespace but I was already imported it then also throw compile time error. 
**I Have installed latest .Net Framework on Windows 8.1 Os.**

How i solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: it seem that u r missing some .not ddls

Comment: but how to update it DLL Files?

Answer (score 1):

I have had that problem before. I was using the latest .net framework and I went to Programs and Features within control panel (if you're using Windows) and selected the box to also run .net framework 3.5 I think it was.

I then shut down my project after saving, restarted my machine and it worked fine

Comment: IEnumerator is in System.Collections and IEnumerator<T> is in System.Collections.Generic. So make sure you have the correct matching.

Answer (score 1):

Close the project from MonoDevelop by doing Right Click. And open the *.sln file manually in MonoDevelop

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debian and I had your error, [this error](https://forum.unity.com/threads/framework-mono-net-3-5-not-installed.448857/), and both was fixed by installing these packages:

```
mono-reference-assemblies-2.0
mono-reference-assemblies-3.5
```

Using APT:

```
sudo apt install mono-reference-assemblies-2.0 mono-reference-assemblies-3.5
```